# addListenerForSingleValueEvent gets executed twice for each record

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the below code and the firebase has 2 records in it.

```
ref.child("Orders").orderByChild("orderid").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            final ArrayList<OrderBean> offlineOrders = db.getWaterOrder();
            if (offlineOrders != null && !offlineOrders.isEmpty()) {
                for (OrderBean eachrow : offlineOrders) {
                    flag = eachrow.getFlag();
                        if (flag.equals("M")) {

                                if (postSnapshot != null) {
                                    if (postSnapshot.child("id").getValue().equals(orderid)) {

                                        postSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                                        OrderBean orderbean = new OrderBean(orderid, vname, quan, price, date, time);
                                        ref.child("Orders").push().setValue(orderbean); //push the record into firebase

                                        orderslist.add(orderbean);
                                        orderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        .......

                                        OrderBean orderbean = new OrderBean(orderid, vname, quan, price, date, time);
                                        orderslist.add(orderbean);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                            ........

                            OrderBean orderbean = new OrderBean(orderid, vname, quan, price, date, time);
                            orderslist.add(orderbean);
                        }

                        }
                    db.editOrderFlag(orderid);

                    }
            else {
                ..........

                OrderBean orderbean = new OrderBean(orderid, vname, quan, price, date, time);
                orderslist.add(orderbean);
            }
            }
                OrderAdapter orderAdapter = new OrderAdapter(Myorders.this, orderslist);
                listView.setAdapter(orderAdapter);
                listView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
                listView.setStackFromBottom(false);
        }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I thought that

```
ref.child("Orders").orderByChild("orderid").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

will get executed once for each record. But it is getting executed twice for each record. As a result my orderslist has duplicates and hence my adapter is displaying each record twice.

Can anyone help me to understand whats wrong with my code?

Thank you

Satya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are looping twice. Once on the `dataSnapshot` and second on `offlineOrders` ArrayList. So in order to solve this problem, take that `for loop` out of your `onDataChange` method or change the logic of your code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you...I think I understand what you are saying. I think , I will have to modify code within my offlineOrders if clause.